# Spark worker and Master container keeps restarting

Tags: docker, apache-spark, containers

Spark worker and Master container keeps restarting, I'm using a Macbook M1, but then I tried in Windows and Macbook Intel processors, it worked on both.

How can I fix it please?

**Spark Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8.18-bullseye

# Install OpenJDK 11
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 && mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
ENV PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
RUN echo $JAVA_HOME

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libzbar-dev bash gcc git libc-dev curl wget vim nano \
    && apt-get install -y iputils-ping telnet openssh-client net-tools \
    man unzip vim-tiny bc openssh-server thrift-compiler netcat sudo \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean

RUN curl -o spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz && \
    tar -xzvf spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz && \
    mv spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3 /opt/spark && \
    rm -rf spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz

ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
ENV PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
ENV PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
ENV PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python3:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
RUN mkdir -p /opt/spark/history
COPY spark-defaults.conf /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ADD spark-master.sh spark-worker.sh /
```

**spark-master.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "History server is sarting ...."

start-history-server.sh

echo "$(hostname -i) spark-master" >> /etc/hosts

/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
```

**spark-worker.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! getent hosts spark-master; then
  sleep 5
  exit 0
fi

/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077 --webui-port 8081
```

**Docker Compose file**

```
version: "3.8"

x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  build:
    context: ./airflow
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres-airflow/airflow
    AIRFLOW_CONN_SPARK_DEFAULT: "spark://spark-master:7077?deploy-mode=client&spark-binary=spark-submit"
    AIRFLOW_CONN_POSTGRES_JOBS: "postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}?sslmode=disable"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__TEST_CONNECTION: "Enabled"
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres-airflow/airflow
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL: 30
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: ${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST}
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: ${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM}
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: ${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD}
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: ${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT}
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: ${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER}
    _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${AIRFLOW_WWW_USERNAME}
    _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${AIRFLOW_WWW_PASSWORD}
    MINIO_ROOT_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_ROOT_ACCESS_KEY}
    MINIO_ROOT_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_ROOT_SECRET_KEY}
    MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY}
    MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY}
    SPARK_HISTORY_LOG_DIR: ${SPARK_HISTORY_LOG_DIR}
  volumes:
    - ./airflow/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow/data:/opt/airflow/data
    - ./airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow/ml:/opt/airflow/ml
    - ./airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres-airflow:
      condition: service_healthy
    # mongo:
    #   condition: service_healthy

services:

  spark-master:
    build: ./spark
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
      - 7077:7077
      - 8080:8080
      - 18080:18080
    environment:
      MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./spark/jobs:/home/ubuntu/jobs_listings
    command: sh spark-master.sh

  spark-worker:
    build: ./spark
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8081-8085:8081"
    environment:
      MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./spark/jobs:/home/ubuntu/jobs_listings
    command: sh spark-worker.sh

  minio:
    hostname: minio
    image: "minio/minio:latest"
    volumes:
      - ./.storage/minio:/data
      - ./minio:/init
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_ROOT_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_ROOT_SECRET_KEY}
      MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SPARK_SECRET_KEY}
      SPARK_HISTORY_LOG_DIR: ${SPARK_HISTORY_LOG_DIR}
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://127.0.0.1:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3

  postgres-airflow:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume-af:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    # profiles:
    #   - backend

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always
    # profiles:
    #   - backend

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8090/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    ports:
      - 8793:8793
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: bash -c "/opt/airflow/config/airflow_init.sh"
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "false"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${AIRFLOW_WWW_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${AIRFLOW_WWW_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_EMAIL: ${AIRFLOW_WWW_EMAIL:-someemail@gmail.com}

  airflow-flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      # - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres-db-volume-dw:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgres/init/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-pgpass}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER:-pguser}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB:-pgdb}
    # command: bash -c "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"

volumes:
  mongo-data:
  postgres-db-volume-af:
  postgres-db-volume-dw:
```

**Worker Logs**

> Executing task: docker logs --tail 1000 -f
> 5480bd769a2f06b72ee8f0e2871ae85dd230bd00093bb3a2c418b9f0c08d657c
>
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.10     spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
> 172.18.0.5      spark-master /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript  *
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

**Master Logs**

> Executing task: docker logs --tail 1000 -f
> 0de5fc384d6b6df4d1208300d98a6bda52d5f11f0a39792579091cdbd5c43b61
>
> History server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript History
> server is sarting .... starting
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer, logging to
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> failed to launch: nice -n 0 /opt/spark/bin/spark-class
> org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript full log
> in
> /opt/spark/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-0de5fc384d6b.out
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
> /opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript  *
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I expected both Worker and Master Spark container to run and access the interface.

Comment: can you share the master/worker logs?